# How to remove special/unwanted characters using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

```
RCVD CALL FROM PTGÇÖS HUSBAND STATING HE SPOKE TO BCBS AND THEY STATED THE BILLING WAS DONE INCORRECTLY AND THIS SHOULD HAVE BEEN BILLED UNDER GÇ£ROUTINE TEST GÇ£ AND NOT GÇ£MEDICAL ISSUEGÇ¥. VERIFY DEMO...YP INBOUND OTHER CALL
```

How would I replace character like ÇÖ,Ç£,Ç¥ from string with blank. Possibly, there could be many other different characters would be present in string.

**Expected output**

```
RCVD CALL FROM PTGS HUSBAND STATING HE SPOKE TO BCBS AND THEY STATED THE BILLING WAS DONE INCORRECTLY AND THIS SHOULD HAVE BEEN BILLED UNDER GROUTINE TEST G AND NOT GMEDICAL ISSUEG. VERIFY DEMO...YP INBOUND OTHER CALL
```

Comment: In general as comment: Do not do it in sql - do it in the layer before. SQL and string manipulation is a - ah - "weak" point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @specialCharacters TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    specialCharacter varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @specialCharacters
VALUES 
    ('Ç¥'),
    ('Ç£'),
    ('ÇÖ')
;

DECLARE @inputString varchar(max)= 'RCVD CALL FROM PTGÇÖS HUSBAND STATING HE SPOKE TO BCBS AND THEY STATED THE BILLING WAS DONE INCORRECTLY AND THIS SHOULD HAVE BEEN BILLED UNDER GÇ£ROUTINE TEST GÇ£ AND NOT GÇ£MEDICAL ISSUEGÇ¥. VERIFY DEMO...YP INBOUND OTHER CALL';
DECLARE @resultString varchar(max) = @inputString;

SELECT
    @resultString = Replace(@resultString, specialCharacter, '')
FROM
    @specialCharacters
;

SELECT @resultString;
```

You can insert into @specialCharacters table all characters to be replaced.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if inputstring is a value coming from the table ?

Comment: Just use select to assign it to variable.